# DB is being updates sometimes in script execution

Tags: php

I'm having some strange issues with the URL shortner script i have coded, i never noticed the issues until the other day, it is pretty basic in it's execution but it is failing in a aprt that actually works from time to time, i'll post the entire code as it's only 1 page incase something is failing below where the issue is happening.

**Code:**

```
<?php
    $pdo = new PDO(sprintf('%s:host=%s;dbname=%s', 'mysql', 'ip', 'db'), 'user', 'pass');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); 
?>

<?php

if (!empty($_GET['u'])) {

    $urlShort = trim($_GET['u']);       

    try {
    
        // Update the hit count ...
        $u = $pdo->prepare('
            UPDATE  `urls`
            SET     `url_hits` = `url_hits`+1
            WHERE   `url_short` = :urlShort
        ');         
        $u->execute([
            ':urlShort' => $urlShort
        ]); 
        
        // Log the referrer ...
        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {     
            $i = $pdo->prepare('
                INSERT INTO `refs` (`ref_owner`, `ref_ref`, `ref_date`)
                VALUES (:r_o, :r_r, :r_d)
            ');         
            $i->execute([
                ':r_o' => $urlShort,
                ':r_r' => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],
                ':r_d' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ]);     
        }   
        
        //die(print_r($u) + print_r($i));   
        
        // Get the short code to redirect to ...
        $r = $pdo->prepare('
            SELECT  `url_link`
            FROM    `urls`
            WHERE   `url_short` = :urlShort
        ');         
        $r->execute([
            ':urlShort' => $urlShort
        ]);
        
        $redirect    = $r->fetch();

        header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
        header('Location: ' . trim($redirect['url_link']));         
        
    } catch(exception $ex) {        
        //die($ex);
    }               
    
} 

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <title><?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?> | URL Shortner</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="FREE URL Shortner services, shorten your URLs on all your social accounts easily ..." />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <h3 class="text-center">&nbsp;</h3>
        
            <?php
            
            if (isset($_POST['submit_shortner'])) {
    
                    // TODO: Fix.
                    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i", $_POST['301_url'])) { ?>
                        <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc;">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Your URL looks <strong>invalid</strong>!</div>
                        </div>
                    <?php }
                    
                    $short = "";
                    if (!empty($_POST['301_customize'])) {
                        // Check if the short code is already in the database ...
                        $dupes = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `url_short` FROM `urls` WHERE `url_short`='{$_POST['301_customize']}'");
                        $dupes->execute();
                        if ($dupes->rowCount() > 0) { ?>
                        <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc;">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Please choose another <strong>custom</strong> name!</div>
                        </div>
                        <?php } else {
                            $short = $_POST['301_customize'];   
                        }               
                    } else {
                        $short = substr(str_shuffle('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'), 0, 5);               
                    }
                    
                    function get_real_ip() {
                        try {
                            if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
                            {
                              $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
                            } else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
                            {
                              $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
                            } else
                            {
                              $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                            }
                            return $ip;
                        } catch(Exception $e) {
                            echo $e->getMessage();      
                        }
                    }                   
                    
                    if (!empty($short)) {                       
                        $pdo->prepare('
                            INSERT  INTO `urls` (`url_link`, `url_short`, `url_ip`, `url_hits`, `url_member_id` ,`url_date`)
                            VALUES  (:url, :urlShort, :ip, :hits, :memberId, :date)
                        ')->execute([
                            ':url' => $_POST['301_url'],
                            ':urlShort' => $short,
                            ':ip' => get_real_ip(),
                            ':hits' => '0',
                            ':memberId' => '0',
                            ':date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                        ]);     
                        
                        // redirect
                        $redirect = "?s={$short}";
                        header('Location: '.$redirect); 
                        die;                    
                    }           
                    
            }
            
            ?>

            <form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            
               <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc;">
            
               <div class="form-group">
                <label for="301_url">Link to shorten</label>
                <input type="301_url" class="form-control" name="301_url" id="301_url" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="http(s)://..." required>
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Paste your long URL here.</small>
               </div>
              
               <div class="form-group">
                <label for="301_customize">Customize your short link (optional)</label>
                <input type="301_customize" class="form-control" name="301_customize" id="301_customize" placeholder="">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Here we use a keyword (case sensitive) instead of a cryptic string. Example: <strong>https://<?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/u/keyword</strong></small>
               </div>
              
               <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" name="submit_shortner" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block"><i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i> Make Wee!</button>
               </div>
               
            </form>
            
    <?php if (!empty($_GET['s'])) { ?>
    
              <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc;">
              
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="301_customize"><strong>Short URL</strong></label>
                <input type="301_customize" class="form-control" id="301_copyInput" value="<?= 'https://'; ?><?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/u/<?= $_GET['s']; ?>/">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Click the icon to copy to clipboard <a href="<?= 'https://'; ?><?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/u/<?= $_GET['s']; ?>/" onClick="return copyFunction()" data-toggle="Copy URL to clipboard"><i class="fas fa-copy"></i></a></small>
              </div>
              
              <hr style="border-top: 1px solid #ccc;">

    <?php } ?>

    <p class="text-center">&copy<?= date('Y'); ?> <a href="https://<?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>">https://<?= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?></a></p>
    
    </div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
            placement : 'bottom'
        });
    });
    </script>

    <script>
    function copyFunction() {
      var copyText = document.getElementById("301_copyInput");
      copyText.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      alert("Copied URL to clipboard!");  
      return false;
    } 
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have taken out the `$pdo` credentials at the top, the problem is, the hits sounter at the top is not incrementing all the time, if i set it back to `0` do a click test in each of the 3 main browsers IE, Chrome, and FF it will increment by 1 fine, it goes no higher, BUT if i comment out this part: `die(print_r($u) + print_r($i))` and then test, it is incrementing as it should (but only using IE), what is also strange is, the redirect at this part: `header('Location: trim($redirect['url_link']));` is working fine, so it is executing the script from the top down as it should.

The referrer code just after the hits count is never getting executed for some reason.

There is no errors to show, another strange issue, it sometimes updates the hit count and other times it doesn't, my `.htaccess` is setup like:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Force www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Force SSL: 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]
# URL Rewrite links.
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]*)\/$ /?u=$1 [L]
```

To use like `siteused.com/u/test` instead of `siteused.com/?u=test` is this somehow the issue? i don't think it is as each time i debug the `u` value is always passed through absolutely fine.

I'm not sure what else to debug, is there anything obvious i have missed or not done properly? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code really isn't fun to read through. You should consider doing some splitting. e.g. moving the DB functions to another class/file and then just call these functions. This will make it a lot easier to maintain.

Comment: This is plan B lol i normally do have it seperate, i thought becuase it was a fairly basic script what could go wrong doing it this way lol if i cannot find this bug i'll need to quickly rewrite it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to [301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) redirects. `header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');`
So once browser gets a 301 status code for any URL say **A**->**B** it will internally "remember" the translation and therefore use that in subsequent hits So never hits A actually when user types in A in the address bar or clicks links for A

What you rather need is [302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) `header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');` because browser won't cache it and your route would get hit everytime

Comment: The only thing is, it's the ```// Update the hit count ...``` part that is failing, the redirect is working fine, would this still be the issue?

Comment: Exactly it fails because of 301 redirect . When browser visits say shortcode from gmail.com for the first time which is `https://yoursite.com/shorturl2` and gets 301 ->moved permanently so because now browser knows that `https://yoursite.com/shorturl2` has moved permanently to gmail.com it won't bother hitting ` https://yoursite.com/shorturl2` anymore so your update code never runs for 2nd,3rd...times

Comment: Hello cow thank you Viney, that was the issue! i didn't think it was but tried and tested :) thank you again.